# npm cannot install packages, access denied to .npm cache folder

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

When running `npm install` on a local project, I get this error:

> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied. The operation was rejected by your operating system. It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user

For unclear reasons, it seems that a global `.npm` folder is causing the troubles.

```
path /Users/erik/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ab/a6/079836a3c186b5fd2d717a4

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied
```

I tried forcing the install with `sudo npm install` but then I get these errors:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
```

Worst of all, it seems that `npm` is no longer working now, when executing any `npm` command I get this very weird error

```
npm -v
```

> const path = i >= 0 ? args[i] : process.cwd(); Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd

How can I fix these permission issues? Even locally I am not allowed to use `npm install`.